# Spring boot 2.3.4 with Swagger + Hateoas

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-2.0, spring-hateoas

While trying to work with Hateoas and Swagger 2.9.0 The application is failed to start with this exception:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method linkDiscoverers in org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration required a single bean, but 17 were found:
    - modelBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
    - modelPropertyBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
    - typeNameProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
    - syntheticModelProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
    - documentationPluginRegistry: defined in null
    - apiListingBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
    - operationBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
    - parameterBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
    - expandedParameterBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
    - resourceGroupingStrategyRegistry: defined in null
    - operationModelsProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
    - defaultsProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
    - pathDecoratorRegistry: defined in null
    - apiListingScannerPluginRegistry: defined in null
    - relProviderPluginRegistry: defined by method 'relProviderPluginRegistry' in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/HateoasConfiguration.class]
    - linkDiscovererRegistry: defined in null
    - entityLinksPluginRegistry: defined by method 'entityLinksPluginRegistry' in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/WebMvcEntityLinksConfiguration.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

I saw some workarounds that should solve this prolbem :

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type=EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
public class AppConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }
    
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LinkDiscoverers discoverers() {
        List<LinkDiscoverer> plugins = new ArrayList<>();
        plugins.add(new CollectionJsonLinkDiscoverer());
        return new LinkDiscoverers(SimplePluginRegistry.create(plugins));
    }
}
```

But it didn't work for me.
Anyone knows how to deal with this problem ?
Here is my build.gradle file :

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.plugin', name: 'spring-plugin-core', version: '1.2.0.RELEASE'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I tried to change the Spring-plugin-core to 2.0.0 version I got this error also:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsManager.createContextBuilder(DocumentationPluginsManager.java:152)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.getPluginFor(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin;)Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin;

The method's class, org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/omera/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.plugin/spring-plugin-core/2.0.0.RELEASE/95fc8c13037630f4aba9c51141f535becec00fe6/spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry: file:/C:/Users/omera/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.plugin/spring-plugin-core/2.0.0.RELEASE/95fc8c13037630f4aba9c51141f535becec00fe6/spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry
```

Answer (score 0):

Just google the error message "Parameter 0 of method linkDiscoverers in org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration required a single bean", and I found a [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/1094), which says spring hateoas is not full compatible with springfox.

Try to upgrade `spring-plugin-core` to 2.0.0.RELEASE as suggested in that github issue.

This is another related [github issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2932). Try suggestions there.